# Get all nodes linked by a specific relationship

Tags: neo4j

I have created a vehicle make called `Toyota` and also created a new node store my vehicle models.

```
CREATE (Make:make{name: "Toyota"}) 
CREATE (Model:model {name: "Camry"})
CREATE (Make)-[r:MODEL_OF]->(Model) 
RETURN Make, Model
```

I added two more vehicle models

```
CREATE (Model:model {name: "Vitz"})
CREATE (Model:model {name: "Corolla"})
```

and linked the two models to `Toyota`

```
MATCH (a:make), (b:model) WHERE a.name = "Toyota" AND b.name = "Vitz" 
CREATE (a)-[r: MODEL_OF]->(b) 
RETURN a,b 


MATCH (a:make), (b:model) WHERE a.name = "Toyota" AND b.name = "Corolla" 
CREATE (a)-[r: MODEL_OF]->(b) 
RETURN a,b
```

How can i return all models of make `Toyota` that have the relationship `MODEL_OF`?

I have tried this

```
MATCH (Make:make {name: "Toyota"})<-[r:MODEL_OF]-(n) 
RETURN n.name
```

and i get

```
(no changes, no records)
```

I have several models of `Toyota` related to `Toyota` so its not supposed to return zero results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your data and your query are using opposite directions.

data:

```
   (:make)-[:MODEL_OF]->(:model)
```

query

```
   (:make)<-[:MODEL_OF]-(:model)
```

So it is no surprise the query returns nothing. One of the two has to be changed.